# How much do I need to sand before proceeding?

Tags: honda, rust, body

I noticed a few days back that the ***upper portion*** of my driver side back wheel has got rust. I took a sand paper and started cleaning it hoping to remove the rust and apply primer-paint on it but as I started sanding it, it got worse - something started coming off! I am not sure if this was the metal or the paint so I sprayed it with some primer and applied some spray paint. I should have taken the picture before spraying it but I panicked!

I was checking online to see how to fix this [Rust Stop Paint](http://www.kbs-coatings.com/). It says I need to sand the rust off but when do I know how to stop sanding? When I kept sanding, I thought the metal was just falling down in pieces. The more I was sanding it, the more it kept falling down so I stopped after a while thinking that I would destroy it completely.

Currently, I am seeing two products, one called the Rust Paint and the other called the Bondo Putty and am not sure which one to use for this purpose. Would anyone have some advice?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks pretty bad - typically when I've seen ones get this corroded, they need to be sandblasted clear of rust, properly filled and then repainted.

You should be able to keep sanding until all the rust is gone - if that leaves holes, you're better off knowing about them rather than having them hidden under rust. If the holes are too big, you can always weld a patch on the inside then fill.

Comment: Ah... I just hope it doesn't fully come out. From what was said about those rust paints, they mentioned that I need to apply it on rust so that it can go and stick to it or something though I don't completely understand the details of it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Legend - the rust paints are good for *small* amounts of rust, but I think you are past that stage:-)

Comment: Oh... Marketing videos are hard to believe these days. :) Thank you once again.